# Sequelize ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables, house, renter.
A house has many renters, a renter only has one house. (house <->> renter).

In Renter:

```
  Renter.associate = function (models) {
    models.renter.belongsTo(models.house, { foreignKey: { name: 'house_id', allowNull: false } } );
  };
```

Or:

```
 Renter.associate = function (models) {
    models.renter.belongsTo(models.house, { foreignKey: { name: 'house_id', allowNull: false, onDelete:'CASCADE' } } );
  };
```

Both ways fail as explained below.

In House:

```
House.associate = function (models) {
    models.house.hasMany(models.renter, { foreignKey: 'house_id'});
}
```

I also tried by omitting the hasMany association and only having the belongsTo part on renter...

when I delete a hosue:

```
await house1.destroy();
```

I get the following error:

```
SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: update or delete on table "house" violates foreign key constraint "renter_house_id_fkey" on table "renter"
```

When I look at the db logs, during the renter table creation it has this:

```
"house_id" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "house" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I need the DB to delete all renters when I delete a house via DB constraint ON DELETE CASCADE. How can I fix this? As far as the table def goes, I can see the `ON DELETE NO ACTION` being a problem, and I am not sure how to get sequelize to put CASCADE not NO ACTION.

Comment: Have you tried adding `hooks: true`?

Comment: For reference - https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7356#issuecomment-300590153

Comment: I have. That unfortunately does not set the right constraint on the table on Postgres. It just allows Sequelize to do the delete at a higher level. I do not want to rely on a "much less proven" solution (no offense). I want to have Postgres take over and enforce deletion rules. So question is, can sequelize set that constraint on the table definition without relying on hooks....